# Xamarin.iOS - Translated UIView resets on navigation to another page

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am developing an `Xamarin.Forms` application in combination with `Prism` which translates an `UIView` based on gestures. When I change the `Transform`/`Center`, and  navigate to another page using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, the `Transform` and `Center` just change back to `Identity`. If I do the same gesture a second time, without closing the page, everything stays fine.

Is this a `Xamarin` bug or am I missing something?

This is the `method` that I use to navigate to another page:

```
private void HandleLongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    if (recognizer.State != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
       return;

    var position = recognizer.LocationInView(this);

    _control?.OnPinAddCommand?.Execute(new Location
    {
        X = (float)position.X,
        Y = (float)position.Y
    });
}
```

Note that the `UIView`'s `Transform` and `Center` are not changed during that event.